# Get date from bank transtions

Tags: java, android

I Want to get all detail from message send by bank In different field I try to get date from these messages
but it could not get all type of date

I get amount from all these but issues in other fields

```
smsDto.setBody("Dear Customer, Your Ac XXXXXXXX5666 is credited with INR8,922.00 on 16 Feb. Info. INF*000080483346*SALARY. Your Net Available Bal is INR 8,922.00.");
        smsDto.setBody("A/c NN5715 debited for Rs 2000; ATM WDL. A/c Bal(sub to chq realisatn) Rs13286.23 on 24APR 21:19hr. Call 1800226999 to block your card if not used by you.");
        smsDto.setBody("Dear Customer, your Account Number XXXXXX6377 has been credited by Rs 215.000 being DBT/DBTL funds transfer on 19/05/2015 - CENTRAL BANK OF INDIA");
        smsDto = new SmsDto();
        smsDto.setBody("Dear Customer, your Account XX0770 has been credited with INR 20,000.00 on 21-Dec-18. Info: BIL*INFT*001602773462*STEALT. The Available Balance is INR 23,547.77.");

    }
AND CODE IS 
String getDate(String msgBody){
        String date="";
        Pattern regEx = Pattern.compile("(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](19|20)\\d\\d");// Pattern.compile("[0-9]*[Xx\\*]*[0-9]*[Xx\\*]+[0-9]{3,}");
        Matcher m = regEx.matcher(msgBody);
        if (m.find()) {
            try {
                Log.e("date= ", "" + m.group(0));
                 date = (m.group(0));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            Log.e("No_matchedValue ", "No_matchedValue ");
        }
        return date;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I see that you are extracting dates from two fields here - 19/05/2015 and 21-Dec-18

For both the above patterns you could try the below regex

```
/* for MM/dd/yyyy */
 regex = /^(0[1-9]|1[0-2])\/(0[1-9]|1\d|2\d|3[01])\/(19|20)\d{2}$/ 
/* for dd-mon-yyyy */
 regex = [0-9]{1,2}-[a-zA-Z]{3}-[0-9]{4}
```